Unity iOS background task download with FirebaseStorage fails
Downloading files from FirebaseStorage on iOS (Unity) doesn't work while the app is locked?
I have a process which periodically checks if a Task is done. Based on the result it triggers a completion/failure method and kills the background process in iOS.
The following mockup works correctly when the screen is locked.
int miliseconds = UnityEngine.Random.Range(10, 20) * 1000;
Task.Delay(miliseconds).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
         Debug.Log("File downloaded...");
         isDone = true;
         isDownloaded = true;
     }
     else isDone = true;
});

The following Firebase method, can't get the downloads to complete while the app is in the background.
 StorageReference pathReference = firebaseManager.Storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(RefURL);
 storageReference.GetFileAsync(IOHelpers.FilePrefix(OutputPath)).ContinueWith(task =>
 {
     if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
     {
         Debug.Log("File downloaded to " + OutputPath);
         isDone = true;
         isDownloaded = true;
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("Failed to download: " + RefURL);
         isDone = true;
     }
  });

Is there anyway to make the firebase method work, in the background, or does it require too much resources for a background task in iOS? Any insight will make my day! Thanks
